# How to add element into HTTP header in SoapWrapper Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, soap

I had no problem running the following code in my controller.

```
SoapWrapper::add(function ($service) {
               $service
               ->name('Testing')
               ->wsdl('http://example.asmx?WSDL')
               ->trace(true);
             });

        // Using the added service
        SoapWrapper::service('Testing', function ($service) use ($data) {
            print_r($service->call('Function1', []));
            //print_r($service->getLastRequestHeaders());
        });
```

Following is my request HTTP header.

```
POST http://example.asmx HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/Function1"
Content-Length: 214
Host: some_host
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
randomName:some_session_id  //<------------which i want to add
```

But let say I want to add `randomName: some_session_id` into the HTTP header, what/how should I do it? Have try `-header()` and `customHeader()` but this only add into the xml envelope header which is not I want.

Answer (score 1):

For adding data into http header you need to do it like it's on [documentation](https://github.com/artisaninweb/laravel-soap)

```
$data = [
            'CurrencyFrom' => 'USD',
            'CurrencyTo'   => 'EUR',
            'RateDate'     => '2014-06-05',
            'Amount'       => '1000'
        ];

        // Using the added service
        SoapWrapper::service('currency', function ($service) use ($data) {
            var_dump($service->getFunctions());
            var_dump($service->call('GetConversionAmount', [$data])->GetConversionAmountResult);
        });
```

In  your case you don't send any additional data in your service call so you should do it like it's below

```
SoapWrapper::add(function ($service) {
               $service
               ->name('Testing')
               ->wsdl('http://example.asmx?WSDL')
               ->trace(true);
             });

        // Using the added service
        $data = session()->get('some_id');
        SoapWrapper::service('Testing', function ($service) use ($data) {
            print_r($service->call('Function1', [$data]));
            //print_r($service->getLastRequestHeaders());
        });
```

**EDIT:**

For adding custom header, you should use

```
public function customHeader($header)
{
    $this->headers[] = $header;
    return $this;
}
```

from `SoapWrapper/Service`.

So in your case you should do something like

```
SoapWrapper::add(function ($service) {
               $service
               ->name('Testing')
               ->wsdl('http://example.asmx?WSDL')
               ->customHeader($customHeader)
               ->trace(true);
             });
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @KuKeC. But too bad this wont add the parameter I want to HTTP header.

Comment: What parameter you want to add in HTTP header?

Comment: see my request HTTP header in question. `randomName:some_session_id `

Comment: something like this? `->customHeader('http',array('randomName'=>'some_session_id'))` ? I get `SoapClient::__setSoapHeaders(): Invalid SOAP header` error

Comment: I think more like `->customHeader('randomName'=>'some_session_id')`

Comment: still cant work if like that since it is syntax error (`unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ')'`)

Comment: Can you show me how you tried to add that custom header in your code?

Comment: change `->customHeader(array('randomName'=>'some_session_id'))` to `->customHeader('randomName'=>'some_session_id')`

Comment: cant..mentioned above, `syntax error (unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ')'`

Comment: Then try `->customHeader('randomName: some_session_id')`

Comment: haha...go back to `SoapClient::__setSoapHeaders(): Invalid SOAP header`

Comment: Hmmm, maybe then `->customHeader(header('randomName: some_session_id'))` ?